# How to upload CSV data to Oracle database, when your Oracle image runs in docker when mistakes Oracle are: 29913, 29400?

Tags: oracle, docker, csv, external-tables

I have issue with uploading files to my database through an external table:

[image: issue]

I can create, read, drop directories, tables by `anton_gridushko` user, but have no idea why I have troubles when I try to load data to created table.

I used [this tutorial](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-external-table/) but did everything in an SQL Developer worksheet.

Could you give me advice, please, what to do?

My commands sequence is

```
1.create directory lang_external as 'C:\loader';
2.SQL> grant read,write on directory lang_external to anton_gridushko;
3.CREATE TABLE languages(
        language_id INT,
        language_name VARCHAR2(30)
    )
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(
        TYPE oracle_loader
        DEFAULT DIRECTORY lang_external
        ACCESS PARAMETERS 
        (FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',')
        LOCATION ('languages.csv')
    );

4. run into issue here:
SELECT 
            language_id, 
            language_name 
        FROM 
            languages
        ORDER BY 
            language_name;
```

Comment: It would be better to include the error message in your question as text, possibly with the external table definition and the directory commands you ran. The file doesn't exist in that directory, as defined in Oracle. The OS-level directory is on the Oracle DB server, so the file has to be there too; though it can be a shared directory (NFS etc.). You may need to clarify your set-up to see where the problem is.

Comment: How can I clarify my setup? What I need to show?